# MS Excel: query for rows where cell A & B are identical but C is different?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2011

I'm trying to clean up some really bad data that I inherited and I'm looking for a way to 'ask' Excel to somehow bring to my attention all rows where cell `A` & `B` match but cell `C` is different.

Example:

```
    A       B       C           
1   cat     dog     cow
2   cat     rat     cow
3   cat     pig     ant
4   cat     dog     pig
5   cat     dog     cow
6   cat     rat     cow
7   gnu     rat     cow
```

Put another way. I want rows 1, 4 & 5 to be brought to my attention because A & B match but C is different. I'd settle for just one of those (1, 4 or 5) to be brought to my attention as I can dig in and figure out the rest.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to highlight row 4, since that is the only row where not all three values match. Cat and dog are also in rows 1 and 5, but in these, the value in column C is the same.

You could use this formula in D1 and copy down:

```
=IF(OR(AND(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$7&$B$1:$B$7=A1&B1))=2,SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$7&$B$1:$B$7=A1&B1),--($C$1:$C$7<>C1))>0),SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$7&$B$1:$B$7=A1&B1),--($C$1:$C$7<>C1))>1),"here","")
```

(It's not an array formula).

Or use Conditional Formatting on the cells C1:C7

[image]

The formula is

```
=OR(AND(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$7&$B$1:$B$7=A1&B1))=2,SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$7&$B$1:$B$7=A1&B1),--($C$1:$C$7<>C1))>0),SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$7&$B$1:$B$7=A1&B1),--($C$1:$C$7<>C1))>1)
```

I added a case where A and B are the same in only two rows and C is different for these two rows. These two should be highlighted as far as I understand the task.

Comment: Very nicely done

Answer (score 0):

There are no matching A and B in your example, but the formula:
    =If(And(A1==B1,A1!==C1),"A1 and B1 match, but C1 doesn't","Other")
Will identify what you want.

Comment: I see the confusion. `A` doesn't *equal* (`=`) `B` but `A+B` is equal on those rows. Hmm... that new definition may lead me to the solution...

Comment: Both row A and row B are the same on 1, 4 & 5. I'd like to know when that's the case but only if row C is somehow different on any row where A & B match up. Hope that makes better sense... which in this case would be so for 1, 4 & 5 but *not* 2, 6 (and 3 & 7 for that matter)

Comment: Ohhh, you are going to need an array formula for that...